# Is there a formula for $\mathcal{L}(f(t+1))$?

Tags: laplace-transform

Is there a formula for $\mathcal{L}(f(t+1))$? in terms of $\mathcal{L}(f(t))$?

I know for example $$ \mathcal{L}(f(t-a)\cdot u(t-a))=e^{-as}\mathcal{L}(f(t)) $$

Comment: I'd say write the integral and use a change of variable.